# Spring Boot - Gradle Exclusions Not Reflecting in Gradle Cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I spent way too much time on this, I am trying to use log4j instead of spring boot logging, Unfortuantley every time i start my sprint boot app i use to get slf4j binding error as below .

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/doddmani/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/ccedfbacef4a6515d2983e3f89ed753d5d4fb665/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/doddmani/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.8.2/36bc2a99b86be26ccdc51fe288458dc712d280c1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
2017-11-21 15:29:51.004  INFO 9692 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-11-21 15:29:51.012  INFO 9692 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2017-11-21 15:29:51.319  INFO 9692 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/faps]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

And I did see there was a dependency in logback.jar when i executed gradle dependency command. I fixed it by adding exclusions in my gradle file as below.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
 }
```

With this fix, i see no more refenrence to logback jars in dependency list, But everytime i run my app again , Its still fetching reference from gradle cache and continues to say SLF4J Binding exceptions. Can any one pls help me getting this issue sorted out.

Comment: Have you read the spring documentation on using log4j? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging it's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem. I was trying add log4j2 to my spring boot app, this config fix it to me

```
configurations.all {
    all*.exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
}
```